# How to update activity UI when i click a button in my notification?

Tags: java, android, service

I made a mediaplayer app which plays songs in the background with a service.
I have a notification which shows the previous, pause/play and next button.

These buttons work but i would like to change my pause/play buttons state in my Activity when i click the pause/play button in my notification.

So when i for example pause the song in my notification, i want it to also change my button in my activity too the pause drawable.

How can i do this?

Code for the notification in my service which handles the buttons state by passing the playBackStatus (Previous, Pause/Play, Next).

```
private void NotificationBuilder(PlaybackStatus playbackStatus){
    int notificationAction = R.drawable.ic_action_pause_white;
    PendingIntent play_pause_action = null;

    if (playbackStatus == PlaybackStatus.PLAYING){
        //Pause button created when song is PLAYING
        notificationAction = R.drawable.ic_action_pause_white;
        play_pause_action = playbackAction(1);


    }else if (playbackStatus == PlaybackStatus.PAUSED){
        //Play button created when song is PAUSED
        notificationAction = R.drawable.ic_action_play;
        play_pause_action = playbackAction(0);

    }
```

EDIT:

**play_pause_action is a PendingIntent**

```
notificationBuilder.setShowWhen(false)
            .setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle().setMediaSession(mMediaSessionCompat.getSessionToken()).setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1 ,2))
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_headset).setContentTitle(activeSong.getTitle()).setContentText(activeSong.getArtist())
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_prev_white, null, playbackAction(3))
            .addAction(notificationAction, null, play_pause_action).addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_next_white, null, playbackAction(2))
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.theme1));

 private PendingIntent playbackAction(int actionNumber) {
        Intent playbackAction = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
        switch (actionNumber) {
            case 0:
                // Play
                playbackAction.setAction(Constants.ACTIONS.mACTION_PLAY);
                return PendingIntent.getService(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
            case 1:
                // Pause
                playbackAction.setAction(Constants.ACTIONS.mACTION_PAUSE);
                return PendingIntent.getService(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
            case 2:
                // Next track
                playbackAction.setAction(Constants.ACTIONS.mACTION_NEXT);
                return PendingIntent.getService(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
            case 3:
                // Previous track
                playbackAction.setAction(Constants.ACTIONS.mACTION_PREVIOUS);
                return PendingIntent.getService(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Button btn=((Button)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay));


if (playbackStatus == PlaybackStatus.PLAYING){
        //Pause button created when song is PLAYING
        btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause); 
        notificationAction = R.drawable.ic_action_pause_white;
        play_pause_action = playbackAction(1);


}else if (playbackStatus == PlaybackStatus.PAUSED){
      //Play button created when song is PAUSED
       btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
       notificationAction = R.drawable.ic_action_play;
       play_pause_action = playbackAction(0);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my app has an Activity with fragments and the buttons are in my MainActivity which doesn't call onCreate/OnResume again so this won't work. I need something that listens when i click a button in my notification and then interacts with my MainActivity notifying the button in my notification was pressed.

Comment: but according to UX , you could not show notification with play/pause button and MainActivity play/pause at once

Comment: I used a pendingIntent that listens for the play/pause state, check my edit

Comment: I have an activity which lists all songs on the device, when i click one it starts playing and build a notification for that song.

Answer (score 0):

Create a interface then you can able to handle button .in your interface add a method like example handleMybutton (View v){ handle your button what ever you want to do }